# Could not detect failed SSD after failed installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, ssd, bootloader, download-manager

I recently purchased Hp 15g2039tu. while installing ubuntu in the free space, installation failed. Thereafter the ssd is not getting recognised. Further the boot loader is not visible so that windows could be started.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu were you trying to install? What errors did you get? Your question needs more detail.

Comment: Can you boot from a live USB and try to access the SSD?

Comment: yes I can boot from usb. i was trying to install 22.04. However ssd is not visibile.

Comment: Check UEFI ("BIOS"). If not recognized there then 1. it failed and 2. it won't be anywhere else, obviously.